# navigation drawer icon animation

Tags: android, fragment

I started writing an app for Android. I have a problem with the `Animation` of the `NavigationDrawer` icon at the top left. It works correctly when the application is launched for the first time but when I pick an item from the list in the `NavgationDrawer` its icon stays in the "open" state even though the `NavigationDrawer closes as it should.

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.res.*;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ActionBarDrawerToggle icon;
    final String[] listContent ={"Accueil","Fiche technique","Pilotes","Ecuries"};
    final String[] fragments ={
            "com.mycompany.f1holo.MainPageFragment",
            "com.mycompany.f1holo.FirstFragment",
            "com.mycompany.f1holo.SecondFragment",
            "com.mycompany.f1holo.ThirdFragment"};

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawer,
                R.drawable.navdrawer,
                R.string.open,
                R.string.close);

        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        list.setAdapter(ad);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        FragmentTransaction transition = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transition.replace(R.id.mains, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[position]));
                        transition.commit();
                    }
                });
                drawer.closeDrawer(list);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.mainMenuAbout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "F1 Holo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.mainMenuQuitter:
                finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_about, menu);
        return true;    
    }
}
```

And here is my `FirstFragment`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FirstFragment frag = new FirstFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout,  null);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, please try to be more clear. Also tell us what you tried so far to fix the problem and explain exactly what problems you encountered.

Comment: when I open the application once the icon drawer navigation works perfectly. but when I click on a section of the drawer, this one closes normally but the icon remains in the open position.sorry for my english

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code correctly? Because there are errors in your `Activity`.

Comment: And please try to format your code properly in the future... I already took care of that this time.

Comment: Errors in your `MainActivity`: In your `onCreate()` method there is something wrong here: `ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.drawable.navdrawer, R.string.open, R.string.close` as you can see there is no closing bracket, no semicolon and that `ActionBarDrawerToggle` at the start also seems wrong. Please check your code you might have made a mistake when copying it to Stack Overflow. And in `onOptionsItemSelected()` in your `Activity` there is a `break;` missing after the `finish();` in the last `case` statement. While its technically not needed it should still be there.

Comment: And what you are trying to do with your `fragments` array at the top is ok, but consider doing it like this instead of hardcoding the `Strings`: `final String[] fragments = { MainPageFragment.class.getName(), FirstFragment.class.getName(), SecondFragment.class.getName(), ThirdFragment.class.getName() };`. This is much better because regardless of if you rename or move the `Fragments` any changes are automatically applied to the array. You don't have to worry about typos or keeping this up to date. Also you can use code completion and if there is an error you notice it when compiling your app.

Comment: I can help you further as soon as you updated your code.

Comment: yes I forgot to copy ); after "string.close". this is corrected. yet he does not tell me error. but the icon does not always returns to its initial position when the drawer navigation is closed.

Comment: Are you sure that otherwise this line is the same as in your code? Because if yes than I found your mistake. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and it is so obvious I could kick myself for not noticing before...

The problem is here:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                FragmentTransaction transition = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transition.replace(R.id.mains, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[position]));
                transition.commit();
            }
        });
        drawer.closeDrawer(list);
    }
});
```

In this `OnClickListener` you are setting a new `SimpleDrawerListener` and therefore overriding this line:

```
drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

This disconnects the `ActionBarDrawerToogle` from the `DrawerLayout` and as a result stops the animations from playing... This is all you need:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        FragmentTransaction transition = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transition.replace(R.id.mains, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[position]));
        transition.commit();

        drawer.closeDrawer(list);
    }
});
```

Why would you want to do this anyway? It just causes a delay between the user picking the item and the content actually changing. If it is because of performance issues - maybe that the close animation of the `NavigationDrawer` is not playing correctly - then doing something like this might be appropriate but in any case if you decide to implement this do it like this:

First create global variable called `drawerItemSelection`:

```
private String drawerItemSelection = null;
```

And then implement your `ItemClickListener` like this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        drawerItemSelection = fragments[position];

        drawer.closeDrawer(list);
    }
});
```

And finally in your `onCreate()` method implement the `ActionBarDrawerToogle` like this:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.drawable.navdrawer, R.string.open, R.string.close) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        if(drawerItemSelection != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transition = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transition.replace(R.id.mains, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, drawerItemSelection));
            transition.commit();

            drawerItemSelection = null;
        }
    }
};
```

If you have any further questions feel free to ask!

Comment: sorry after checking the code is exactly the same. I do not understand why the icon remains open after clicking on a fragment of the drawer navigation position.

Comment: Now the icon will remain closed when I click on a drawer of navigation elements.

Comment: Ok well then override `onDrawerOpened()` too and also call `syncState()` in there and see if it works. Both of those things should not be necessary, but if that fixes the problem it should be ok.

Comment: yes adding onDrawerOpened () its ok but that the position of the icon is just open or closed, without animation

Comment: I will try to reproduce the problem, give me a few hours and I might have a solution.

Comment: now it signal an error on super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView) (unknow method). I tried several changes but is the case for change does not occur

Comment: On the line "super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView)". onDrawerClosed not recognized.

Comment: Well where do you mean exactly? The `super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView)` in my code or in your code?

Comment: I change my code based on yours but the error persists.

Comment: really sorry. after checking it works perfectly. a big thank you

Comment: I am glad I could help! Please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful to you, this indicates to other people that this answer solved your problem and we both get a little reputation for it.